# PHP strtotime is off by one day

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp, strtotime

```
//Convert string to unix timestamp
strtotime( "04/05/2014" );

//Insert into database, convert from unix timestamp first
$sql = "INSERT INTO database ( date ) VALUES ( FROM_UNIXTIME(:date) )";
```

It's saving to database as `2014-04-04 15:00:00` when I expect it to be `2014-04-05 00:00:00`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's an odd way to go about converting the date to a new format.

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: Looks like GMT wasn't respected

Comment: its not off by one day, it looks like its off by 7 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Unix timestamp is a fixed moment in time. However, MM/DD/YYYY dates are relative pieces of data that depend on time zone.

When you do this:

```
strtotime( "04/05/2014" );
```

... you tell PHP to calculate the timestamp that corresponds to midnight in PHP time zone. You then do this:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(:date)
```

... and tell MySQL to calculate the local time (regarding MySQL time zone) that correspond to the timestamp. Thus the shift.

---

Time zone conversions in SQL are difficult so I'd avoid them at all cost. I'd feed MySQL with a string that already contains the appropriate local time, e.g.: `2014-04-05` or `2014-04-05 00:00:00`. That string is easy to calculate from PHP.

As about PHP, either set the time zone explicitly:

```
$ts = strtotime( "04/05/2014 +02:00" );
```

... or adjust the default zone to your liking:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
```

I'd also recommend you get familiar with the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class—it's way more powerful than good old timestamps.

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation about the downvote. I'm specially interested in PHP date handling and I'd love to correct any erroneous information I've written.

Comment: I'd be interested in the reason for the downvote as well, because I think Alvaro has provided a valid explanation as to the observed behavior i.e. MySQL `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function uses the "current time zone" (that is, the setting of the `time_zone` variable in database session) in evaluating the return value.

Answer (score 4):

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` 

becouse of this  set **your** **timezone** and it will work

---

**Enjoy :)**

Comment: Thank you. Although your answer is direct, the explanation provided by Alvaro helped me understand the larger picture. =)